# Saving top score in a file

Tags: c

So I want to save the best 3 scores of the game and to put them on a file. But for some reason when I read the file the best scores are 53,32,32. Not using name for now, just the 3 scores. And also I'm not familiarized with files.

```
typedef struct score{
    unsigned char score[3];
    //char name[20];
} SCORES;
```

This is how I'm saving.

```
void guardar_highscore (SCORES top){

FILE *f;

f = fopen ("/var/www/html/highscore3.txt","wb");
if (f ==NULL)
    perror ("nope2"),exit (1);
fprintf(f,"%d \n %d \n %d \n",top.score[0],top.score[1],top.score[2]);

fclose(f);
}
```

This is how I'm reading it to the struct.

```
SCORES ler_highscore (){
SCORES top={0};
int i=0;
char line[20];

FILE *f;
f = fopen ("/var/www/html/highscore3.txt","rb");
if (f ==NULL) 
    perror ("nope"), exit (1);

while(fgets(line,20, f) != NULL){
    sscanf (line, "%c", &top.score[i]);
    i++;
}
fclose(f);

return top;
}
```

Comment: Re: “best scores of the game”, what game? Re: “When I read the file the best scores are 53,32,32”, are those the best scores? What are you expecting?

Comment: Why are you storing scores as `unsigned char`? An `int` would be more appropriate. You write the scores as an integer, but when you read them back in, you read them as a single `char`. That's not going to go well. You're probably getting the ASCII values, 32 is a space and 53 is a 5.

Comment: @coreyward it is a rogue like game using html and C. And 53,32,32 are not the best scores, i don't know what they represent also because it should be 0,0,0 when i run it for the first time... I expect to be able to read the scores from the file to the struct, modify the struct values with the score that i will get and then write it back on the file.

Comment: @Schwern I was using unsigned char because of the range of the score. I was playing with Int but when i got like 127 it just came down to 0 again..

Comment: @Schwern It's working now using Int, and it's doing what i want, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct score{
    unsigned char score[3];
    //char name[20];
} SCORES;
```

Scores are generally numbers, so it doesn't make much sense to store them as a single character. The problem becomes clear when you notice that you're writing them as integers (and with an extra space)...

```
fprintf(f,"%d \n %d \n %d \n",top.score[0],top.score[1],top.score[2]);
```

But you're reading them as characters...

```
sscanf (line, "%c", &top.score[i]);
```

53, 32, 32 looks suspiciously like the ASCII numbers for `5` and two spaces. If you write the character `5` as a number you'll get 53. That's because the character `5` *is* the number 53. Have a look at [the ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) to see why.

---

The solution is to use integers consistently.

```
typedef struct {
    int score[3];
} Scores;
```

Note that `ALL_CAPS` is generally reserved for constants, not types.

`guardar_highscore` remains basically the same, though I've cleaned it up some.

```
// The filename is now a variable so its used consistently
// and can be used in error messages.
const char Score_File[] = "highscore3.txt";

void guardar_highscore(const Scores *top) {
    FILE *fd = fopen (Score_File,"wb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        // A more informative error message than "nope".
        fprintf( stderr, "Could not open '%s' for writing: %s\n", Score_File, strerror(errno) );
        exit(1);
    }

    // Loop instead of repeating the formatting. This makes adding more
    // scores easier.
    // Note the stray whitespace is gone. 
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        fprintf(fd, "%d\n", top->score[i]);
    }

    fclose(fd);
}
```

`ler_highscore()` changes to read as integers. It also only reads three lines to protect against overflowing the 3 element list if the file is unexpectedly large. It's good practice to ***never trust your input***.

```
Scores ler_highscore() {
    // This is the proper way to initialize a struct,
    // each field must be initialized separately.
    // A bare {0} happens to work because the struct is
    // currently just a list, and if it doesn't you're
    // going to overwrite all the elements anyway.
    Scores top = { .score = {0} };

    // No reason to skimp on the size of the line buffer.
    char line[1024];

    FILE *fd = fopen(Score_File, "rb");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        // Again, more informative error message.
        fprintf( stderr, "Could not open '%s' for reading: %s", Score_File, strerror(errno) );
        exit (1);
    }

    // Read 3 lines, no more. Otherwise we'll overflow memory.
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        // Use `sizeof(line)` rather than repeating the number.
        // It avoids mistakenly letting them go out of sync.
        if( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd) == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "Not enough scores in %s\n", Score_File );
            break;
        }

        // Read one integer per line.
        sscanf(line, "%d", &top.score[i]);
    }

    fclose(fd);

    return top;
}
```